# take sum of similar column from multiple data table based on unique id in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have four datatables like

```
Table 1
id        name           Afee        Insfee
1         a              100        10
2         b              100        10

Table 2
id        name           Bfee        Insfee
2         b              100        10
1         a              100        10
3         c              100        10

Table 3
id        name           Cfee        Insfee
1         a              100        10
3         c              100        10


Table 4
id        name           Dfee        Insfee
1         a              100         10
2         b              100         10
```

in the crystal report i want to get the result as

```
Name       Afee      Bfee      Cfee     Dfee     Insfee    total
a          100       100       100      100      40         440
b          100       100       0        100      30         330
c          0         100       100      0        20         220
```

where this INSfee should be the sum from all the four table for a particular ID and
total should be the sum of a row in that in that report.

How to do this in a sap crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of Insfee, Create a formula and add the field (Insfee) from all tables using sign "+" and place it adjacent to afee, dfee... etc.

Now to get the total use below code:

1. Create formulas for all fileds(afee,bfee...etc) in below code I named those as a, a1,a1.
2. Now create a another formula for "total" and implement below code

Place the formulas in detail section, You will get result.

```
EvaluateAfter({@a});
EvaluateAfter({@a 1});
EvaluateAfter({@a 2});

{@a}+{@a 1}+{@a 2}
```

Comment: how can i join those for data tables based on ID to get sum, Means i had ID = 1 in all four data tables so for that ID i need to get the result as table fields( Name       Afee      Bfee      Cfee     Dfee     Insfee    total) row value (
a          100       100       100      100      40         440)

Comment: For this you need to edit the afee formula. Create formula as if Id=1 then "Value of the field" else 0. This will create the report as required and then apply formula I provided that will add all the values in a row and displays the result